# Optimal Count() operation from a DB using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, performance, t-sql, linq-to-sql

DBAs have told me that when using T-SQL:

```
select count(id) from tableName
```

is faster than

```
select count(*) from tablenName
```

if id is the primary key.

Extrapolating that to LINQ-TO-SQL is the following accurate?

This LINQ-to-SQL statement:

```
int count = dataContext.TableName.Select(primaryKeyId => primaryKeyId).Count();
```

is more performant than this one:

```
int count = dataContext.TableName.Count();
```

Comment: What DBAs have told you that?  They are usually interpreted the same by the optimizer.

Comment: On most RDBMS, that is not going to make any difference whatsoever... and *if it did* (which it usually won't), `count(1)` would be, potentially, even better. However, re your final "is more performant" question - have you tried it? in particular, trap the SQL used for both queries, see if that is different. If it *is* different, run it both ways with stats-io enabled, etc.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs would you like his SSN? :) - Seriously: it was someone who I worked with and took it on face value and never questioned it. From the comments and accepted answer it looks like what I was told is false. Thanks to everyone for clearing this up!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand it there's no difference between your two `select count` statements.

Using LINQPad we can examine the T-SQL generated by different LINQ statements.

For Linq to SQL both

```
TableName.Select(primaryKeyId => primaryKeyId).Count();
```

and

```
TableName.Count();
```

generate the same SQL

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value] FROM [dbo].[TableName] AS [t0]
```

For Linq to Entites, again they both generate the same SQL, but now it's

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[TableName] AS [Extent1]
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old one but watch out with sql server! Count does not count null values so the two statements may not be equivalent if your primary key field is nullable. see

```
create table #a(col int null)

insert into #a values (null)

select COUNT(*) 
from #a;

select COUNT(col)
from #a;
```